# How to count rows which have at least 1 value in their columns?

Tags: excel, algorithm

[image]

I want to find all the names (rows) which have atleast 1 value in the columns labelled 1, 2, 3, 4. How do I do that? For example, in the pic that will be A, D, E, F, G, H, etc.

Comment: Solved. First I did COUNTBLANK for each row. Then I summed each column's count & subtracted from total number of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the next column (assuming that all i see in the picture is all there is that would be F) use `=IF(SUM(B2:E2) > 1, 1, 0)` then at the bottom of that column sum all the ones and zeros :)
hope that helps

Answer (score -1):

In case you are dealing with non numerical values, try this approach. 
in cell `F3` enter this formula `=IF(4-COUNTA(B3:E3)=4,"",A3)` and drag it to the bottom. Now if you simply want to count number of rows that match your criteria, in cell F1 enter this `=SUM(IF(LEN(F3:F2600)>0,1,0))` formula using CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER combination since it is an array formula. In case you want to list all names in column `A` which pass condition, you can use this formula `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,F3:F22)` in cell `G1`. Please note that this formula is available in latest Excel version (2016 or 365).

[image]